# Dynamic programming with string keys in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, memoization

Being rather new to pure functional programming idiom, I can't get how to implement this case of dynamic programming. I have a function `f :: String -> [String]` which is calculated recursively and want to memoize it. Input `String`s can be arbitrary, so I guess that something like a lazy `Map` is needed, but couldn't find any. How to implement such case in Haskell?

Comment: Have you looked on Hackage? There's about a dozen memoization libraries available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a memoizer library:

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

f :: String -> [String]
f = Memo.list Memo.char memof  -- because String = [Char]
    where
    memof x = ... f ...          -- call *f* recusively (not memof)
```

See the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.3/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html) for more.  Also see [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MemoTrie/0.5/doc/html/Data-MemoTrie.html)

Comment: I didn't think that it's implemented as an external library and didn't search search at hackage. And it seems strange that such functions are not in the default GHC libraries.